# Is there an intuitive reason why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx$ doesn't exist but $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \int_{-N}^N xdx$ exists?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

Is there some intuitive reason why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx$ doesn't exist but $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \int_{-N}^N xdx$ does? It would seem they represent the same thing (area beneath $f$ everywhere), but apparently not.

Consider the following problem from Ch. 14 "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 27 (b) The improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^a f$ is defined in the obvious
> way, as $\lim\limits_{N\to -\infty} \int_N^a f$. But another kind of
> improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f$ is defined in a
> nonobvious way: it is $\int_0^{\infty} f + \int_{-\infty}^0 f$,
> provided these improper integrals both exist.
>
> (b) Explain why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx$ does not exist. (But
> notice that $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \int_{-N}^N xdx$ does exist)

My calculations are as follows

$$\int_{-N}^N xdx = \left . \frac{x^2}{2} \right |_{-N}^N=\frac{N^2-(-N)^2}{2}=0$$

On the other hand

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx=\int_{-\infty}^0xdx+\int_0^{\infty}xdx$$

$$=\lim\limits_{N \to -\infty} \int_{N}^0 xdx+\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int_0^{N} xdx$$

$$=\lim\limits_{N\to -\infty} \left . \frac{x^2}{2}\right |_N^0+\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \left . \frac{x^2}{2} \right |_0^N$$

$$\lim\limits_{N\to -\infty} \frac{-N^2}{2}+\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \frac{N^2}{2}$$

Neither of these limits exists.

This seems like a weird result.

Furthermore, if we had defined $\int_{-\infty}^a f$ as $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \int_{-N}^a f$ then in the calculation above we would have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx=\int_{-\infty}^0xdx+\int_0^{\infty}xdx$$

$$=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^0 xdx+\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int_0^{N} xdx$$

$$=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \left ( -\frac{(-N)^2}{2}+\frac{N^2}{2} \right )$$

$$=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} 0$$
$$=0$$

Comment: The limit is also called "principle value". If the integral exists , its value is equal to the principal value, but it need not exist as this example shows.

Comment: $\frac{(-N)^2}{2}+\frac{N^2}{2}=N^2 \color{red}{\neq} 0$

Comment: Your penultimate line is incorrect, as Giorgos points out.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis there should be a negative sign in front of the first term. The result is 0.

Comment: @evianpring In that case the result is $-\infty+\infty =\text{undefined} \color{red}{\neq}0$

Comment: True, I can't join the limits so that line is incorrect because of that fact.

Comment: @wasn'tme not sure what idea you attempted to get across.

Comment: @Peter ... "principle value" -> "principal value".

Answer (score 5):

“Filling” the line with intervals of the form $[-N,N]$ is just a particular way of doing it. Yes, it's symmetric and indeed this particular way gives rise to what's called “Cauchy principal value”.

But we'd like the integral, if it exists, to be independent of the way we fill the line. Why not
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{N^2} x\,dx
$$
or some other way? Note that
$$
\int_{-N}^{N^2} x\,dx=\Bigl[x^2/2\Bigr]_{-N}^{N^2}=\frac{N^4-N^2}{2}
$$
and the limit is $\infty$.

Your final argument is flawed: you can do
$$
\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)+\lim_{x\to c}g(x)
$$
provided, in the right hand side,

1. both limits exist finite or
2. one limit is finite and the other is infinite or
3. both limits are $\infty$ or
4. both limits are $-\infty$

with obvious meaning of $+$ in cases 2, 3 and 4.

Your case does not fit, because
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N x\,dx=\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^0 x\,dx=-\infty
$$

Comment: Okay, so the last example is flawed. Regarding the first part, I'm not sure I understand what the answer is to the the question of why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$ is different from $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^N xdx$? Should I learn what Cauchy principal value is or is there a way to explain these concepts that doesn't rely on having to know what that concept is?

Comment: @evianpring As I explained, we want that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ is independent of the covering we use for computing, so it's $\lim_{(a,b)\to(\infty,\infty)} \int_{-a}^b f(x)\,dx$ and you can easily see that this doesn't converge for $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly. In the limit $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^N xdx$, the integral is being computed from $-N$ to $N$, and we "expand" outwards equally in both directions from $0$. The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$ is a more "general" concept: it represents the general notion of "expanding" outwards in both directions from $0$, but with the "rates of expansion" on either side possibly being different. Is this roughly the idea?

Comment: @evianpring Yes, that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that "real infinity" (i.e., $\infty$) is a concept, not a number.  We tend to think of infinity as a number, but it is really an entire group of numbers.  That's why you can't perform a lot of arithmetic operations using $\infty$.  It would be like doing arithmetic operations on "odd" or "even". Sure, there are some things we can do, but not a lot.

With hyperreal numbers, however, you can be much more exact, since hyperreal numbers refer to specific values of infinity, not just the concept in general.  There are a lot of different notations for hyperreal numbers, but the one I prefer is to use $\omega$ (greek lowercase omega) as a "unit" infinity.

Then, your limit becomes much more reasonable, because you have specified *which* infinity you are talking about.  That's why your limit works when your integral doesn't (since $N$ can only take one value, you are forcing both parts to be the same infinite value).  If you want to do your integral using hyperreal, it is straightforward enough:

$$ \int_{-\omega}^{\omega} x\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2}\biggr|_{-\omega}^{\omega} = \frac{\omega^2}{2} - \frac{(-\omega)^2}{2} = 0 $$

Note that this is the same reason that the Cauchy rearrangement theorem works - by treating $\infty$ as a number when it is really a concept you get weird results.  The rearrangement theorem goes away if you use specific hyperreal values rather than a general "infinity".